# "Application not installed", is it a bug of ADT?

Tags: android, adt, android-install-apk, message-digest

I exported an apk by ADT in eclipse, and I attempted to install this apk into a avd, but it raised "Application not installed".

I checked the logcat, and found this:

```
W/PackageParser(59): java.lang.SecurityException: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF has invalid digest for res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png in /data/app/vmdl25264.tmp
E/PackageParser(59): Package com.ep.android has no certificates at entry res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png; ignoring!
```

In the file "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" of the apk, I found this:

```
Name: res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png
SHA1-Digest: 4ss2KZ3FzkmfE6HAAsVu0aJKx1U=
```

So I tried to use my own Java Programming generate a SHA1-Digest for the png file, and the result is "sjmKOs4BYDXg7COdeTc8tIfPBR0=" which is totally different.
My Java code for generate a SHA1-Digest is:

```
public static void main(String[] filename) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        Exception {

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    FileInputStream in =  new FileInputStream("./ic_launcher.png");
    int bytes = 0;
    while ((bytes = in.read()) != -1) {
        md.update((byte)bytes);
    }

    in.close();
    byte[] thedigest = md.digest();
    System.out.println(Base64Encoder.encode(thedigest));
}
```

It seems both the avd and my code consider that the SHA1-Digest in MANIFEST.MF of apk is invalid.
So, I guess the SHA1-Digest generator in ADT did something wrong here. Is it a bug? Or I missed something?

Comment: check whether application is already installed on emulator or not

Comment: No, it is not. The problem is about the SHA1-Digest in MANIFEST.MF generated by ADT, I guess it has a bug. Both the avd and my code consider the digest is invalid.

Comment: The digest generated by my own Java Programming is `sjmKOs4BYDXg7COdeTc8tIfPBR0=`. It doesn't equal `4ss2KZ3FzkmfE6HAAsVu0aJKx1U=` which is in the MANIFEST.MF file of the apk generated by ADT.

Comment: And I found this exception in logcat:`java.lang.SecurityException: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF has invalid digest for res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png`.

Comment: And not all the digest in the MANIFEST.MF is wrong. I have tested the other png files and got the same digests as ones in the MANIFEST.MF. Like :`Name: res/drawable-mdpi/ic_tab_news_s.png
SHA1-Digest: ikGDamqvj1SvxM4deMMO7u0YN0Y=`

Name: res/drawable-mdpi/ic_tab_profile.png
SHA1-Digest: bJJ1aomZ9WpFnBIkogwxVriOPQs=

Comment: Only the "ic_launcher.png" file's digest is invalid. How to upload a file to here? I want to show this png file, so you guys can test it.

Comment: Ok, the png is here :[ic_launcher.png](http://212137.gov.cn/apk/ic_launcher.png).You can build a simple android project including this png file in the res/drawable-mdpi/ directory. And exported the apk by ADT. When you install it in an AVD or a real phone, it will turn up the problem.

Comment: tested your file working fine with me

Comment: Really? Could you please show me your apk? I wanna check the differeces from mine. Or you could show me the SHA1-Digest in `MANIFEST.MF`.

Comment: My email: hardPass@126.com, many thanks!

Comment: Akki: your apk doesn't work in my machine : Application not installed!
`05-18 01:54:50.095: W/PackageParser(59): Exception reading res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png in /data/app/vmdl55069.tmp
05-18 01:54:50.095: W/PackageParser(59): java.lang.SecurityException: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF has invalid digest for res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png in /data/app/vmdl55069.tmp
05-18 01:54:50.095: E/PackageParser(59): Package com.Afdaf has no certificates at entry res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png; ignoring!`

Comment: Akki: I also checked MANIFEST.MF in your apk, and found the SHA1-Digest was `4ss2KZ3FzkmfE6HAAsVu0aJKx1U=`.  My avd version is android 2.2. You said it works with you. I wonder how , I wonder why. And the apk is here :[apk_by_Akki.apk](http://212137.gov.cn/apk/Test.apk). Could anybody else test it for me ?